# my unit test case is failing for the PUT api controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have created a Basic CRUD api.i have written test cases for all the api's ,Every test cases works fine but not PUT. It always gives me Resource Not Found Error.

**model**

```
package com.example.crudrestapi.model;


import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String gstin;
    private float outstandingBalance;
}
```

**Test**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(CrudController.class)
class CrudControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;
    
    @Test
    void putApiTest() throws Exception {

        Customer customer = Customer.builder().build();
        given(customerRepo.findById(Long.parseLong("1"))).willReturn(Optional.of(customer));

        mockMvc.perform(put("/customers/{customerId}", 1)
                .content("{ \"name\" : \"test\", \"address\" : \"test\" }")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

**controller**

```
@PutMapping("customers/{customerId}")
    public Customer updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer newCustomer, @PathVariable Long customerId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {

        return customerRepo.findById(customerId)
                .map(customer -> {
                    if (newCustomer.getName() != null)
                        customer.setName(newCustomer.getName());
                    if (newCustomer.getGstin() != null)
                        customer.setGstin(newCustomer.getGstin());
                    if (newCustomer.getPhoneNumber() != null)
                        customer.setPhoneNumber(newCustomer.getPhoneNumber());
                    if (newCustomer.getAddress() != null)
                        customer.setAddress(newCustomer.getAddress());
                    if (newCustomer.getOutstandingBalance() != 0.0f)
                        customer.setOutstandingBalance(newCustomer.getOutstandingBalance());
                    return customerRepo.save(customer);
                }).orElseThrow( () ->new ResourceNotFoundException());

    }
```

**Error i'm Getting**

```
2020-12-29 08:36:04.789  INFO 2564 --- [           main] c.e.c.controller.CrudControllerTest      : Starting CrudControllerTest using Java 11.0.9 on Acer-Aspire7 with PID 2564 (started by Ashil in C:\Users\Ashil\Documents\Java+SpringBoot\crudRestApi)
2020-12-29 08:36:04.792  INFO 2564 --- [           main] c.e.c.controller.CrudControllerTest      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-29 08:36:06.607  INFO 2564 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-29 08:36:07.103  INFO 2564 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2020-12-29 08:36:07.103  INFO 2564 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2020-12-29 08:36:07.106  INFO 2564 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2020-12-29 08:36:07.155  INFO 2564 --- [           main] c.e.c.controller.CrudControllerTest      : Started CrudControllerTest in 2.943 seconds (JVM running for 5.294)

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = PUT
      Request URI = /customers/1
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"39"]
             Body = { "name" : "test", "address" : "test" }
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudController
           Method = com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudController#updateCustomer(Customer, Long)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = java.lang.IllegalStateException

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"18"]
     Content type = text/plain;charset=UTF-8
             Body = Resource Not Found
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
Expected :200
Actual   :404
<Click to see difference>


    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
    at com.example.crudrestapi.controller.CrudControllerTest.putApiTest(CrudControllerTest.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)

2020-12-29 08:36:07.506  INFO 2564 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

i don't understand why i get **404**.The Object is not created by the builder..??

Should i specify the **id** in the builder..??

Comment: what is the content type for the POST API?
Also, what is the structure of your customer class?

Comment: I have added the model above.Content type of POST api is " MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mock the `save()` method on your repository as well. Returning `null` from the `Optional.map()` method will return an empty Optional, which will cause the `orElseThrow()` to execute its supplier.

See [Optional.map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-).